# Allowing emails with a plus (+) symbol to land in the same Zimbra mailbox

Tags: email, settings, postfix-mta, zimbra

I want to allow emails like myusername+something@mydomain.com instead of simply myusername@mydomain.com using Zimbra - this is a feature on Gmail.

Does anyone where to begin looking to allow this to work? Postfix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, postfix is the right place.  Look at [`recipient_delimiter`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) in the `postconf` docs:

> **recipient_delimiter (default: empty)**
>
> The separator between user names and address extensions (user+foo). See canonical(5), local(8), relocated(5) and virtual(5) for the effects this has on aliases, canonical, virtual, relocated and on .forward file lookups. Basically, the software tries user+foo and .forward+foo before trying user and .forward.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> recipient_delimiter = +
> ```

Answer (score 9):

How to implement this in Zimbra is available on the official Zimbra wiki here:

http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Plus_Addressing

Zimbra stores a lot of Postfix parameters in LDAP so modifying the running Postfix config won't work.

To enable Plus Addressing with Zimbra, use zmprov as follows:

```
zmprov mcf zimbraMtaRecipientDelimiter +
```

Note that the delimiter can be a character other than '+'.

To disable Plus Addressing, use zmprov as follows:

```
zmprov mcf -- -zimbraMtaRecipientDelimiter +
```

After making changes to enable or disable this feature, it may be required to restart tomcat. Postfix should pick up the changes automatically, though it may take a couple minutes to register.

Comment: [Please provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.